# Magento 2.3 aroundCreate() of \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder not called

Tags: magento2.3, image, plugin, magento2.3.4

I have create a plugin to change image object and call image url directly from AWS S3 instead of magento.

Function should be call on any page where product image will be loaded.

di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder">
      <plugin name="add_product_object_to_image_data_array_new" type="<vendor>\<module>\Plugin\Block\Catalog\Product\ImageBuilder" sortOrder="100" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

File: vendor\module\Plugin\Block\Catalog\Product\ImageBuilder.php

```
<?php

namespace <vendor>\<module>\Plugin\Block\Catalog\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;


class ImageBuilder
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function aroundCreate(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder $subject,
        callable $proceed
    ) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r("test");
        exit;

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

I tried to call plugin but nothing happening and it's calling core function only.

I tried :

- bin/magento setup:upgrade
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- bin/magento setup:di:compile
- bin/magento index:reindex
- bin/magento cache:flush

still nothing works. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check

If there is any other module is overriding the class by
preference.For which you want to add your plugin.

Check if its in developer mode.

Remove the generated/code/ and flush cache

Make sure Module is available in Config.php

Answer (score 1):

You're forgot to pass argument in **aroundCreate()** and **proceed()** method. Just use this below code and check log file.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Catalog\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class ImageBuilder {

    public function aroundCreate(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product = null,
        string $imageId = null,
        array $attributes = null
    ) {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/Rohan.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Your text message');
        return $proceed($product, $imageId, $attributes);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi rohan can you please check this out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/321040/magento-2-saving-custom-form-data-to-custom-table?noredirect=1#comment460010_321040